# UnWanted Custom field added in the wp page edit area

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I have made a plugin in which post meta required ? Now i get unwanted custom field.
[image]
Here is code that i am using to add custom meta in post type= recommendation

```
add_meta_box('plugin-recommendation-box', 'Recommendation', 'add_plugin_recommendation_box', 'recommendations', 'normal', 'default');


    function add_plugin_recommendation_box(){
    global $post;
    $title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_title1', true);
    $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_price', true);
    $reg_price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_reg_price', true);
    $rating=    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_rating', true);
    $pros=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_pros', true);
    $cons=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_cons', true);
    $specs=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_specs', true);
    $url=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_url', true);
    $custom_url=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_url', true);
    $rec_short_dec=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rec_short_dec', true);
    $ratings=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_ratings', true);
    $trybtn=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_trybtn', true);
    $curr=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recommendation_currency', true);
    $compare_subtitle=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_subtitle', true);
    $compare_price_1=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_1', true);
    $compare_price_2=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_2', true);
    $compare_price_3=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_3', true);
    $compare_price_4=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_4', true);
    $compare_price_plan_1=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_plan_1', true);
    $compare_price_plan_2=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_plan_2', true);
    $compare_price_plan_3=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_plan_3', true);
    $compare_price_plan_4=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_plan_4', true);
    $compare_price_plan_short_desc=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_plan_short_desc', true);
    $compare_price_short_desc=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'compare_price_short_desc', true);
    $offer_price_short_desc=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_price_short_desc', true);
    $offer_sale_text=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_sale_text', true);
    $offer_image=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_image', true);
    $offer_subtitle_text=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'offer_subtitle_text', true);
    $coupon_code=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coupon_code', true);
    $coupon_detail=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coupon_detail', true);
    $coupon_start_date=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coupon_start_date', true);
    $coupon_end_date=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coupon_end_date', true);
    $top_10_basic_feature1=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_basic_feature1', true);
    $top_10_basic_feature2=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_basic_feature2', true);
    $top_10_basic_feature3=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_basic_feature3', true);
    $top_10_basic_feature4=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_basic_feature4', true);
    $top_10_basic_feature5=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_basic_feature5', true);
    $top_10_advance_feature1=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_advance_feature1', true);
    $top_10_advance_feature2=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_advance_feature2', true);
    $top_10_advance_feature3=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_advance_feature3', true);
    $top_10_advance_feature4=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_advance_feature4', true);
    $top_10_advance_feature5=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'top_10_advance_feature5', true);
    $rec_expert_feature1=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rec_expert_feature1', true);
    $rec_expert_feature2=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rec_expert_feature2', true);
    $expert_feature1_title=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expert_feature1_title', true);
    $expert_feature2_title=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expert_feature2_title', true); 
    $expert_trend=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expert_trend', true);   
    $sch_popup_feature1=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sch_popup_feature1', true);
    $sch_popup_feature2=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sch_popup_feature2', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide this in the screen options, there should be a checkbox for "Custom Fields"

Comment: Thanks, @ben Casey It just simple and i am finding it in codes of my website - https://smarthostingprice.com

Comment: All good, we have all been there ;)